# Validate controls in winform (with Devexpress)

Tags: .net, winforms, validation, devexpress

I am using WinForms in .NET and DevExpress 3rd Party Components.
How can I validate the data of multiple components in a Form and summarize them in a customized way?

Comment: The question seems very generic. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
using DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider;

// ...
ConditionValidationRule containsValidationRule = new ConditionValidationRule();
containsValidationRule.ConditionOperator = ConditionOperator.Contains;
containsValidationRule.Value1 = '@';
containsValidationRule.ErrorText = "Please enter a valid email";
containsValidationRule.ErrorType = ErrorType.Warning;

CompareAgainstControlValidationRule compValidationRule = 
    new CompareAgainstControlValidationRule();
compValidationRule.Control = notEmptyTextEdit;
compValidationRule.CompareControlOperator = CompareControlOperator.Equals;
compValidationRule.ErrorText = "Please enter a value that equals to the first editor's value";
compValidationRule.CaseSensitive = true;

CustomValidationRule customValidationRule = new CustomValidationRule();
customValidationRule.ErrorText = "Please enter a valid person name";
customValidationRule.ErrorType = ErrorType.Warning;

dxValidationProvider1.SetValidationRule(containsTextEdit, containsValidationRule);
dxValidationProvider1.SetValidationRule(compareTextEdit, compValidationRule);
dxValidationProvider1.SetValidationRule(customTextEdit, customValidationRule);

// Represents a custom validation rule.
public class CustomValidationRule : ValidationRule {
    public override bool Validate(Control control, object value) {
        string str = (string)value;
        string[] values = new string[] { "Dr.", "Mr.", "Mrs.", "Miss", "Ms." };
        bool res = false;
        foreach(string val in values) {
            if(ValidationHelper.Validate(str, ConditionOperator.BeginsWith, 
                val, null, null, false)) {
                string name = str.Substring(val.Length);
                if(name.Trim().Length > 0) res = true;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Source: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument9481